# CDH Community Edition Upgrade from 5.7 to 5.13 without Cloudera Express or Cloudera Enterprise

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I am having a cluster like below -

1. 3 Hbase Master (1 Active & 2 standby)
2. 4 Region Servers
3. 4 Data Nodes
4. 1 Primary & 1 Secondary Name Node
5. 3 Journal Node
6. 4 Nodemanager
7. 3 Resource Manager (1 Active & 2 standby)

**Query 1**

What should be the order of stopping, upgrading & starting of components if I am manually upgrading the package via "1 Click" package as mentioned [here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/manager/5-0-x/Cloudera-Manager-Managing-Clusters/cm5mc_upgrade_cdh5_using_packages.html#xd_583c10bfdbd326ba--6eed2fb8-14349d04bee--7dcb__section_nkc_dfw_rl)? Is it like below:-

1. Stop, Upgrade & Start all data nodes one by one.
2. Stop, Upgrade & Start region servers one by one
3. Stop, Upgrade & Start Upgrade HBase standby nodes one by one
4. Stop, Upgrade & Start Secondary Name Node
5. Upgrade Primary Name Node
6. Upgrade Journal Nodes
7. Upgrade HBase Master
8. Stop, Upgrade & Start standby Resource Manager one by one
9. Stop, Upgrade & Start Active Resource Manager
10. Stop, Upgrade & Start Nodemanagers one by one.

**Query 2**

If I don't follow any order and update the services in the nodes in parallel, will I face any issue (as this is just a minor version upgrade)?

**Query 3**

If I am taking the entire cluster down by stopping all the services in all the nodes and upgrading and then starting? What order should I follow while starting the services?